# Lottery: one bet with n numbers vs n bets with one number

Tags: probability, lotteries

May someone help me with this probability problem, please?

In a lottery game, one random number between N numbers is choosen. One player chooses $n<N$ numbers in a single game. Other player chooses just one number for each $n$ games he plays. Question: Which player has the higher probability of winning the game?

Now what I know. First player probability of winning is : $\frac{n}{N}$

Probability of second player loses every game: ($1-\frac{1}{N})^n$

Probability of second player wins at least one game: $1-[(1-\frac{1}{N})^n]$

So, now I only need to prove that $\frac{n}{N}$ is higher or lower than $1-[(1-\frac{1}{N})^n]$ knowing that $N>n>1$, since for $n=1$ the probabilities are equivalent. I've tried and tried, but no success.

Also, I'm open to different solutions, but I'm in my third week of college, so I may understand only high school math.

Lastly, this is my first post in this forum and English is not my first language, so if there's something I did wrong, please tell me so I can change it.

Comment: Hint: When $0<x<1$ and $n > 1$, ${(1-x)}^n > 1-nx$. Now take $x = 1/N$.

Comment: The expected number of wins is the same in both cases, but the second player can potentially win several times, while the first can only win once (or not at all), so the second player must have a lower probability of winning at least once.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBarber , but I think my biggest doubt is how to prove that ${(1-x)}^n > 1-nx$ is really true

Comment: Thanks @Henry , but if the second player can potentially win several times, how this implies that he have a lower probability of winning?

Comment: @Matheus Because the expected number of wins is the same, something in the expectation calculation needs to offset the second player's positive probability of winning more than once.  That offset is that the probability of winning $0$ times must be higher for the second player than the first player when $n>1$, i.e. the probability of winning at least once is lower for the second player than the first player.